# can I restore the commit message along with a stash?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer, commit-message

Visual Studio 2019 Team Explorer has a new feature that allows me to stash my current changes. 
When I invoke it (with or without --keep-index) it uses the current content of the commit message window as the stash title. Then it clears the commit message.
When I pop the stash (with or without --index) it doesn't do anything with the stash title, so the commit message window stays empty.
Taken together a round-trip (stash + pop) clears the commit message which is a bit annoying.

Can I make VS restore the commit message from the stash title? That would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

We do not currently have the ability to restore the stash message during apply/pop.  If you haven't already, can you please file this as a suggestion request at http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com?  This will ensure the request is added to the feature backlog for consideration.